# Android Studio window on Ubuntu is too large

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio Window on Ubuntu is too large, I increased screen resolution to maximum but it's still too big. (I use Lenovo G480)

Some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

Please help me fix this!

Comment: If you set the launcher to auto-hide, you will get more room horizontally;  the top row of icons in Android Studio will probably collapse to one line, giving more room in the vertical direction too.

Comment: Yeah, That is last solution,  but is this hardware compatible problem?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `hidpi=false` to `<android studio root>/bin/idea.properties` is a possible solution.

Else try to explore the doc about high-density display:  [Troubleshoot Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#high-density)
.